# What is the issue with my classpath? (Java)

Tags: java, classpath, command-prompt

I've been using NetBeans to do all the compilation/classpath work for me, but I wanna give it a go:

Below is what I was typing into command prompt. **Can somebody point out why java cannot find the class and how do I help it find the class?**

```
C:\Users\Dziugas>set CLASSPATH=C:\Users\Dziugas\Desktop\Project\path;

C:\Users\Dziugas>cd desktop\Project\path

C:\Users\Dziugas\Desktop\Project\path>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is D89C-971F

 Directory of C:\Users\Dziugas\Desktop\Project\path

26-Nov-14  11:27    <DIR>          .
26-Nov-14  11:27    <DIR>          ..
26-Nov-14  11:27               420 Path.class
26-Nov-14  11:25               161 Path.java
               2 File(s)            581 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  264,542,785,536 bytes free

C:\Users\Dziugas\Desktop\Project\path>java Path
Error: Could not find or load main class Path
```

I read in the oracle docs that my classpath should be set to the main package. My class is in a package called path:

Desktop > Project > path > Path.class

Path.java straight from notepad++ as requested:

```
package path;


public class Path {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("It's Working!");

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please paste some snap of Path.java

Answer (score 0):

Set your class path **upto the project level** not at the package level.

```
c:\>set CLASSPATH=C:\Users\Dziugas\Desktop\Project
```

Then type the following command to execute the program,

```
c:\>java path.Path
```

Comment: What is the lifespan of this classpath? permanent or just during that particular instance of cmd?

Comment: @Dziugas: environment variables set this way apply only within that command window. But that's the suggested way. You don't want to set a "global" CLASSPATH anyway.

Comment: @Jaya Ananthram Thank you. When I have enough rep, I will upvote :)

Comment: It will lives until closing the console.